# Change Display Scaling mode from 'Default' to 'More Space' in terminal/script

Tags: terminal, script, resolution

I find myself switching between macOS scaling modes often, depending on what I'm doing. Some tasks require me to use the 'More Space' option, while I prefer regular browsing and use in the Default mode.

Is there any way to change between these without hopping into System Preferences? Preferably from Terminal or using a script, which could be hooked up to Shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge…

You could just change the default zoom in the browser, then you wouldn't have to keep changing the display.

[image]

If you wish, you can bulk select & remove existing sites to save dialling them all in separately, then define a new default underneath.
You can decide how much zoom you'd prefer by using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>+</kbd>  or  <kbd>-</kbd>  on a web page & checking the number as it changes in the prefs pane.

Comment: This would only solve something on websites, and not in the UI of the actual OS. Also, zooming out on web pages looks way worse than the Scaling Mode in System Preferences.

Comment: @LucasFrayBurchardt "Some tasks require me to use the 'More Space' option, while I prefer regular browsing and use in the Default mode.", so his idea is to use "More Space" for the entire OS and zoom in for all websites ("When visiting other websites"). I think this solution makes sense to your problem, unless you have some apps that you want to be zoomed in as well. Zooming in on the browser should not look bad.